Spring Data JPA validation fails after update to spring-boot 3.3.0
I'm trying to update spring-boot 3.2.3 -> 3.3.0. I'm running into issues with validating JPA queries that worked in spring-boot 3.2.3.
public record Summary(
    long productionRunId, long productId, String productLengthName, long count, double volume) { }

  @Query(
      """
      SELECT new com.example.Summary(
        t.productionRun.id,
        t.product.id,
        t.productLengthName,
        COUNT(*),
        SUM(t.volume)
      )
      FROM Tag t
      GROUP BY t.productionRun.id, t.product.id, t.productLengthName
      """)
  List<Summary> getSummaries();

Caused by: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Missing constructor for type 'Summary'
    at app//org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitInstantiation(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1506)
    at app//org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitInstantiation(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:275)
    at app//org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$InstantiationContext.accept(HqlParser.java:4029)
    at app//org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSelectableNode(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1453)
    at app//org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSelection(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1407)



Debugging:
The bug seems to be in SemanticQueryBuilder.visitInstantiationArgument. It finds that the nodeJavaType of Summary.productionRunId is Void when it should be long. As a result, Hibernate can not find a "matching" constructor. It's strange that it gets the other 4 constructor arguments correct, but the first one wrong.


Please add your Tag entity.
